# Jenkins slave is not able to access powershell modules

Tags: powershell, jenkins

There is a Jenkins node running at Windows Server 2012 R2 host.
There is a build job with "Windows PowerShell" step and command

```
Import-Module -Name:'WebAdministration'
```

Job is failing with error

> Import-Module : The specified module 'WebAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

If I'm logging in as user which is running that node then manual execution of
`Import-Module -Name:'WebAdministration'` is fine.
  The same job after manual module import will work for some time and then it starts failing again.

Could anyone give a tip what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check if you are running the same 32 or 64 bit powershell in both cases? Is the jenkins user local admin?

Comment: In both cases 32 bit powersehll is used. Jenkins user has a local admin grant. Problem appear after Jenkins master restart but I don't have idea how this issue could be linked with restart.

Comment: Check the value of `$env:PSModulePath` for the Jenkins user.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates the running instance could not find the module file. I'd recommend try `Import-Module` with absolute path to the slave

e.g, you module is placed on `C:\PSModule\Webadmin` folder on the slave

```
Import-Module "C:\PSModule\Webadmin"
```

This should point to the desired module file and resolve the problem.
Alternatively, you can give `add-pssnapin WebAdministration` a shot, might land different result.